# Call javascript function in MVC

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following javascript function in the head of a view

```
function addMarker(title, description, lon,lat, iconT) {
    var icon = new OpenLayers.Icon(iconT);
    var markerslayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers("Markers");
    var lonlat = new OpenLayers.LonLat(lon, lat);
    lonlat = lonlat.transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), map.getProjectionObject());
    var markerToAdd = new OpenLayers.Marker(lonlat, icon);
    markerToAdd.icon.imageDiv.title = title + "  -  " + description;
    markerslayer.addMarker(markerToAdd);
    map.addLayer(markerslayer);
    map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher());
}
```

I am trying to call the function above by using either:

```
@if (Model != null)
{
    foreach (var item in Model)
    {                
    <script type="text/javascript">
            addMarker(@item.Title, @item.Description, @item.Longitude, @item.Latiude, @item.Icon);
    </script>
    }
}
```

or alternatively

```
 public ActionResult Index()
 {
     List<CommonLayer.Map> userMaps = new BL.Map().getUserMaps(User.Identity.Name);
     foreach (var item in userMaps)
     {
         Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "CallMyFunction", "MyFunction()", true);
     }

     return View(userMaps);
 }
```

What am I doing wrong? The view code is not calling the addMarket function whilst the c# code cannot be called from inside the `foreach` since it is not static

Comment: first one should work\

Comment: First one: Is your `addMarker` function declared above the `foreach` loop in your view? Are you seeing any console errors?

Comment: What does the generated HTML/JS look like? Are there quotes around Title and Description?

Comment: try putting single quotes like : ``addMarker('@item.Title'....)``

Comment: You are mixing server side and client side code there, are you sure that is what you want?

Comment: by putting single quotes it will work....

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@if (Model != null)
{
    foreach (var item in Model)
    {
    <script type="text/javascript">
            addMarker('@item.Title', '@item.Description', @item.Longitude, @item.Latiude, @item.Icon);
    </script>
    }
}
```

Also, this line has the `icon` misspelled (must be `iconT` instead of `icon`:

```
var markerToAdd = new OpenLayers.Marker(lonlat, icon);
```